# TikZ, set distance between vertical line and label

Tags: tikz-pgf

In this TikZ code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- node[midway,below,rotate=90] {label} (0,5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I would also like to set a custom distance between the label and the line.

I tried to set `below = 5pt`, but it moves the label down, towards the point `(0,0)`: instead, I would like to move it towards right, increasing the distance between the label and the line.

How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.5cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- node[below=5pt,sloped] {label} +(0,4);
\draw (2,0) -- node[right=5pt,anchor=north,rotate=90] {label} +(0,4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**edit:**

- see the difference between how label is rotated in the above mwe and how you tried to rotate it;
- rotating of nodes also rotates the meaning of `above`, `right` etc.;
- using `rotate` option require to change the node options as shown for the second line;
- it is sufficient to load `tikz` ones;
- if you have a node in the middle of coordinates as in your example (and in the above mwe), it isn't necessary to explicitly define the position, so you can left out `midway` from the node options.